# SonarQube nonconstant String in SQL statements

Tags: sonarqube

I'm scanning my code with SonarQube and I'm getting the following bugs:

-A prepared statement is generated from a nonconstant String 
-Nonconstant string passed to execute method on an SQL statement

I have an sql query to which I append based on some conditions.

Example:

```
PreparedStatement ps = null;

StringBuilder sql = new StringBuilder("UPDATE" + tableName + " SET some_field = ? WHERE a_field = a_value");

if (myObject.getField1() != null) {
   sql.append(" AND Field1 = " + myObject.getField1());
}

if (myObject.getField2() != null) {
   sql.append(" AND Field2 = " + myObject.getField2());
}

if (myObject.getField3() != null) {
   sql.append(" AND Field3 = " + myObject.getField3());
}

if (myObject.getField4() != null) {
   sql.append(" AND Field4 = " + myObject.getField4());
}

...

**ps = connection.prepareStatement(sql.toString());** //generating bug

if (myObject.getSomeField() == null) {
   ps.setNull(1, nevermind);
} else {
   ps.setString(1, myObject.getSomeField());
}
```

I tried passing a final String = sql.toString(); to the prepareStatement() function and it still generates the bug.

Answer (score 1):

The issue that's being raised is that you're assembling your SQL command with concatenation: which table to update, which columns to set and what values to put in them.

You should find a way to hard code the table and columns and use parameter binding for the values.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot hardcode the columns because I will add them to the query only if they meet certain conditions. Is hardcoding the only solution?